# How can we delete entity in jhipster application

Tags: jhipster

I am new to Jhipster application. 
I have created entity. But now i want to delete this entity.

could you please anyone tell me about command and help me on this activity.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it must be done manually.

The easiest way is to revert the git commit of the entity creation. This is why it's a good practice to always commit after entity creation.

Beside deleting files, you may also want to create a Liquibase changelog to drop the entity's table.